# jQuery, find next element with id

Tags: jquery, css, find

I have the following HTML:

```
<input id="A1" type="radio" name="A">
<label for="A1">A1
<div class="menu" id="menu1">   
    <img class="button" id="edit1" src="Aa.png">
    <img class="button" id="remove1" src="Ab.png">
</div>
</label>

<input id="A2" type="radio" name="A">
<label for="A2">A2
<div class="menu" id="menu2">   
    <img class="button" id="edit2" src="Aa.png">
    <img class="button" id="remove2" src="Ab.png">
</div>
</label>
```

I'm trying to have the menu for each label to appear when hovering over the label. For example: when hovering over A1, menu1 should appear.

I tried playing the following code:

```
$("label").hover(
  function() {
    $("this").next(".menu").css( "display", "inline-block" );
  }
);
```

I tried selecting the menu with "children", "next", "nextAll", no luck.

Comment: Change `$("this")` to `$(this)`.

Comment: Why does the menu div is inside the label?

Comment: You can achieve this trivially with CSS rather than using event handlers: `label:hover .menu { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.menu` element is not the *next* element (sibling) after the `label`, it's a *child* element. So you want `children` (or `find` if it could be deeper), not `next`:

```
$("label").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children(".menu").css( "display", "inline-block" );
  }
);
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here you used `this` as a string but it is a reference and menu is children of `label`
So try like this.

```
$(this).children(".menu").css( "display", "inline-block" );
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohammad said, it's supposed to be this, and not "this".
Also, I was supposed to use children, as @Era said.